# Footnote span over two columns in twocolumn document

Tags: footnotes

I have a simple Latex code with article.cls with twocolumn option.

```
\documentclass [11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}

\makeatletter
\newbox\abstract@box
\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\global\setbox\abstract@box=\vbox\bgroup
     \hsize=\textwidth\linewidth=\textwidth
    \small
    \begin{center}%
    {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation}
  {\endquotation\egroup}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@maketitle\expandafter{\@maketitle
  \ifvoid\abstract@box\else\unvbox\abstract@box\if@twocolumn\vskip1.5em\fi\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author[1]{The first author\footnote{Corresponding author:
\\
The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone .}}
\author[2]{The second author}
\affil[1]{University 1}
\affil[2]{University 2}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\footnote{The first footnote.
The first footnote. The first footnote.
The first footnote.The first footnote.
The first footnote.}
 Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone.
vamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique 
neque.\footnote{The secont footnote. The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone}
\end{document}
```

I get a PDF document with text in two columns and with footnotes in two columns. However, I want to have a document in which the footnotes will be in one column (footnotes span over two columns). Note: I do not want to use the\ begin {multicols} {2} option but only the option that is specified: \documentclass [11pt, twocolumn] {article}

[image]

If someone knows how to solve this problem and show it through the example, I'll be grateful.

Comment: are you got any solution ?

Comment: May I know, your problem get fixed?

Comment: It would be great if you could offer a solution.