# Place footnotes at the bottom of floats in twocolumn mode

Tags: footnotes, two-column

How can I place footnotes automatically at the bottom of floats in `twocolumn` mode? `stfloats.sty` works only for single-column documents, could you please provide a solution for this? Please find my MWE placed below:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\fnbelowfloat

\begin{document}
The traceability is of paramount importance and considered as a prerequisite for businesses for long-term functioning in today’s global supply chain. The implementation of traceability can create visibility by the systematic recall of information related to all processes and logistics movement. The traceability coding tag consists of unique features for identification, which links the product with traceability information, plays an important part in the traceability system. In this paper, we describe an innovative technique of product component-based traceability which demonstrates that product’s inherent features—extracted using deep learning—can be used as a traceability signature. This has been demonstrated on textile fabrics, where Faster region-based convolutional neural network (Faster R-CNN) has been introduced with transfer learning to provide a robust end-to-end solution for coded yarn recognition. The experimental results show that the deep learning-based algorithm is promising in coded yarn recognition, which indicates the feasibility for industrial application.\footnote{The traceability is of paramount importance and considered as a prerequisite for businesses for long-term functioning in today’s global supply chain.} The experimental results show that the deep learning-based algorithm is promising in coded yarn recognition, which indicates the feasibility for industrial application.\footnote{The traceability is of paramount importance and considered as a prerequisite for businesses for long-term functioning in today’s global supply chain.}

\begin{table*}[!b]
\caption{Specifications of coded yarn classes.}
{\tabcolsep0pt\begin{tabular*}{480pt}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}ccccccccccc@{}}
\hline
Represented digit & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4} \\
No. of twists per meter & \multicolumn{2}{c}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{800} \\
Color composition & 2 White & 1 Black & 1 White & 2 Black & 2 White & 1 Black & 1 White & 2 Black & 2 White & 1 Black \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}}{}\end{table*}

The traceability is of paramount importance and considered as a prerequisite for businesses for long-term functioning in today’s global supply chain. The implementation of traceability can create visibility by the systematic recall of information related to all processes and logistics movement. The traceability coding tag consists of unique features for identification, which links the product with traceability information, plays an important part in the traceability system. In this paper, we describe an innovative technique of product component-based traceability which demonstrates that product’s inherent features—extracted using deep learning—can be used as a traceability signature. This has been demonstrated on textile fabrics, where Faster region-based convolutional neural network (Faster R-CNN) has been introduced with transfer learning to provide a robust end-to-end solution for coded yarn recognition. The experimental results show that the deep learning-based algorithm is promising in coded yarn recognition, which indicates the feasibility for industrial application.

The traceability is of paramount importance and considered as a prerequisite for businesses for long-term functioning in today’s global supply chain. The implementation of traceability can create visibility by the systematic recall of information related to all processes and logistics movement. The traceability coding tag consists of unique features for identification, which links the product with traceability information, plays an important part in the traceability system. In this paper, we describe an innovative technique of product component-based traceability which demonstrates that product’s inherent features—extracted using deep learning—can be used as a traceability signature. This has been demonstrated on textile fabrics, where Faster region-based convolutional neural network (Faster R-CNN) has been introduced with transfer learning to provide a robust end-to-end solution for coded yarn recognition.

The traceability is of paramount importance and considered as a prerequisite for businesses for long-term functioning in today’s global supply chain. The implementation of traceability can create visibility by the systematic recall of information related to all processes and logistics movement. The traceability coding tag consists of unique features for identification, which links the product with traceability information, plays an important part in the traceability system. In this paper, we describe an innovative technique of product component-based traceability which demonstrates that product’s inherent features—extracted using deep learning—can be used as a traceability signature. This has been demonstrated on textile fabrics, where Faster region-based convolutional neural network (Faster R-CNN) has been introduced with transfer learning to provide a robust end-to-end solution for coded yarn recognition. The experimental results show that the deep learning-based algorithm is promising in coded yarn recognition, which indicates the feasibility for industrial application.

\end{document}
```

Comment: A float (like `table` and `table*`) is designed to float, i.e., you're not sure which page it will appear in. However, your footnotes don't start from within the table in your example; instead, they start from the *main text* that is set in `twocolumn` mode. If I understand right, what you would like is to have these footnotes set in one-column mode at the bottom of the page, and this has no connection with floats. If this is correct, please clarify it in the question, or last least confirm it here. Did you try with `multicols` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462432/73317)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Footnote span over two columns in twocolumn document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439922/footnote-span-over-two-columns-in-twocolumn-document?rq=1). Although this doesn't print footnotes spanning the whole page width, you may be interested in reading the documentation of [ftnright](https://ctan.org/pkg/ftnright), because its author @FrankMittelbach is an expert in LaTeX and multicolumn layout, explains—if I understood well—why he rejected this approach and proposes a ready-to-use alternative.

Comment: Footnote need to be placed bottom of page not table footnote, we used twocolumn option in the template, so that we cannot use particular page multicols package.